# How to set file compatibility settings during install

Tags: wix

I need to change the compatability setting to "Run as Administrator" on one of the files I am installing.  How can I do this?

Using WiX Toolset v3.11.2 on Visual Studio 2015 for Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Compatibility settings are only intended to be enabled by the end user for a program that is no longer being updated. You are supposed to use the application manifest to indicate that it must be run as an administrator. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10).